# Link between macro lncRNA and DNA looping

Tags: dna, rna, transcription

I was wondering if anybody knows some publication about macro lncRNA (very long unspliced RNAs) or more generally a transcribed RNA that may lead to cis-DNA looping of genomic regions overlapped by the (macro) lncRNA transcript ?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't actually understand the phenomenon that you are describing. You mean a long RNA binds to different regions of DNA (in *cis*) causing them to come together?

Comment: It's more the act of transcription of a long RNA that may lead to bring distant chromosome regions closer by the act of 3D DNA conformation.

Comment: I don't think the act of transcription, per-se will bring DNA domains together. It would open up the chromatin. However the "act of transcription" has been said to precede recruitment of Polycomb/Trithorax complexes and these in turn can recruit chromatin remodellers/enhancers etc.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have in mind a recent paper talking about it ?

Comment: I haven't read a recent paper on this. I was doing a project on Polycomb in my UG and that is when I read this in an annualreviews article. It has been 7 years since then. I am sure more research must have been done on this. But in general this concept itself is quite dubious. I can only suggest you directions to look at. Another thing that you can look for is pervasive transcription.